# Cookies not working in ie7

Tags: cookies, iframe, internet-explorer-7

I have two pages on two different domains example1.blogspot.com (a Blogspot blog) and example2.com (my own domain, static page). Both pages contain an iframe which loads the same document from a third domain, example.org. The iframe's document contains a small JS web app which calls example.org via AJAX, one of the calls is a POST request and the server sets a cookie with the response.

Upon reloading the pages, the cookie on example1.com seems gone, i.e. jQuery's [$.cookie()](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) returns null. On example2.com, everything is fine. This happens only in IE7 - IE6, Safari and Firefox all behave as expected. What's wrong with IE7?

Thanks, Simon

**edit:**

Oh well, stupid me ;-) It looks like I have a race condition between some event handlers and a `window.setTimeout` call when deciding whether to check for cookies...sorry!

Answer (score 1):

So if `$.cookie()` returns null, What does `document.cookie` show? Also have you taken a look in IE7's list of cookies to see if the cookie is actually there? Also check that PATH and DOMAIN settings on the cookie are correct.

Comment: I see the cookie in Temporary Internet Files, but it looks like I have an error somewhere else (see my edit). Thanks for helping!

Comment: Please either answer your own question,, or mark my question as the correct one.